# Creating a class that returns Address after fetching location in Android

Tags: java, android, asynchronous

I am trying to create an all in one location fetcher class in Android that will fetch the location and return the `Address` instance.

This class combines asking the user for location permission, showing permission rationale, showing the error message if location could not be fetched and an AlertDialog with a ProgressBar which will show when location is being fetched and hide itself when location is found or an error occurs.

This is my current work:

```
public class LocationFetcher {

    static Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
    AlertDialog alertDialog;
    Context context;
    View retry;

    LocationFetcher(Context context, View retry) {
        this.context = context;
        this.retry = retry;
        handler.post(() -> {
            alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
                    .setTitle("Trying to fetch location...")
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .create();
            alertDialog.setView(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.progress_dialog, null));
        });
    }

    void showErrorMessage() {
        handler.post(() -> {
            alertDialog.dismiss();
            new Builder(context)
                    .setTitle("Error getting location data")
                    .setMessage("Please check the location settings in the Settings app and try again")
                    .setPositiveButton("Retry", (dialog, which) -> {
                        retry.performClick();
                        alertDialog.dismiss();
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton("Cancel", (dialog, which) -> {
                        // do nothing
                    }).show();
        });
    }

    Address getLocation() {
        final int LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Task<Location> locationTask = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(context).getLastLocation();
            handler.post(alertDialog::show);
            try {
                return Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().submit(() -> {
                    boolean flag = true;
                    while (flag) {
                        if (locationTask.isComplete()) {
                            if (locationTask.isSuccessful()) {
                                Location location = locationTask.getResult();
                                if (location != null) {
                                    List<Address> addresses = null;
                                    try {
                                        addresses = new Geocoder(context, Locale.getDefault()).getFromLocation(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), 1);
                                    } catch (IOException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                    if (addresses != null) {
                                        alertDialog.dismiss();
                                        return addresses.get(0);
                                    }
                                    else showErrorMessage();
                                } else showErrorMessage();
                            } else if (locationTask.getException() != null)
                                showErrorMessage();
                            flag = false;
                        }
                    }
                    return null;
                }).get(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            } catch (ExecutionException | InterruptedException | TimeoutException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                showErrorMessage();
            }
        } else // if permission is not there, show permission rationale
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale((Activity) context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION))
                handler.post(() -> {
                    new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
                            .setTitle("Permission rationale")
                            .setMessage("This permission is required to access your location. Without it, the app cannot get your location to serve you better.")
                            .setPositiveButton("Ok", (dialog, which) -> {
                                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) context, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
                            }).setNegativeButton("Cancel", (dialog, which) -> dialog.dismiss())
                            .show();
                });
            else // if rationale not needed, ask for permission again
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) context, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
        return null;
    }
}
```

The problem I am facing with it lies in these parts of the code:

The constructor:

```
handler.post(() -> {
            alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
                    .setTitle("Trying to fetch location...")
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .create();
            alertDialog.setView(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.progress_dialog, null));
        });
```

And showing the dialog in the actual GetLocation method:

`handler.post(alertDialog::show);`

Basically what is happening here is since the `handler.post` part in the constructor works as an asynchronous operation, sometiems the `handler.post(alertDialog::show);` line is executed before the `alertDialog` is created which results in the `GetLocation` method throwing a `NullPointerException`.

How do I wait for the constructor and the async task (or convert async to synchronous) to finish before the `alertDialog` is used?

Edits:

Edit 1:
Note:
I want to call the GetLocation method asynchronously ie I call the function something like this:

```
Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().execute(() -> {
                    LocationFetcher locationFetcher = new LocationFetcher(this, tvCurrentLocation);
                    Address address = locationFetcher.getLocation();
                    });
```

Comment: Why do you create alertDialog asynchronously ? Just create it synchronously in constructor and it should be ok.

Comment: @Yoleth I forgot to mention something. I have added it in the edit, please check.

Comment: Still the same answer, you are already in another thread than main thread, so create alertdialog synchronously :)

Comment: @Yoleth You cannot create UI elements in a non UI thread. It throws an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your alertDialog synchronously and call your method `getLocation` in your new thread :

**Constructor**

```
LocationFetcher(Context context, View retry) {
    this.context = context;
    this.retry = retry;
    alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
            .setTitle("Trying to fetch location...")
            .setCancelable(false)
            .create();
    alertDialog.setView(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.progress_dialog, null));
}
```

**And method call**

```
LocationFetcher locationFetcher = new LocationFetcher(this, tvCurrentLocation);
Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().execute(() -> {    
    Address address = locationFetcher.getLocation();
});
```

Comment: I can't believe how unbelievably stupid I've been. Thanks a ton. BTW, you forgot to remove the `handler.post` in the constructor part of the answer.